# How to Load JS File at the Top?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I load my custom JavaScript file the following way:

In:

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

I put:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

And it works!

However, the custom.js script is loaded at the bottom of the <head> tag. How can I load custom.js to be the first script loaded? Thanks for any help.

Comment: order doesn't matter for scripts included in the <head> tag. the browser will wait for all scripts to load before it starts executing anything.

Comment: It's not for something in the body. I need to load some polyfills needed by the rest of scripts. I know it can be done, I just haven't been able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the head tag from `default_head_blocks.xml`

Try to include your js file into `default.xml`

> app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<head>
   <script src="js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

just add above had the tag before the body tag

Run below commands

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Doesn't work. It is still not the first JS file included! A bunch of other scripts are first. mixins.js, requirejs-config.js and require.js. I need custom.js to be the top JS file.

Comment: In my case it display in head tag

Comment: try this way <link src="js/custom.js"/> maybe it help

Comment: It displays, but not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom module and load your script.

Try the following code

**app/code/Anshu/Js/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    deps: ['Anshu_Js/js/custom-js']
};
```

The path for `custom-js.js` would be `app/code/Anshu/Js/view/frontend/web/js/`

Here Anshu is the namespace and Js is my custom module name.

Here I am loading my javascript module on every page before any other module is loaded by declaring global `require js` dependency using `deps`.

I am hoping that this will serve the purpose functionality point of wise.

Comment: I want to load my JS file from app/design/frontend/nameSpace/magento-luma-child-theme/web/js/custom.js. How do I do it?

Comment: @GTSJoe Then write code of requirejs-config.js file your theme's requirejs-config.js file that will be the same.

Comment: How? Can you show me? I've never used require-config.js before.

Comment: you can add requirejs-config.js in app/design/frontend/NameSpace/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/

Comment: I have no module, I just created a custom theme. How can I create one?

Comment: @GTSJoe app/design/frontend/NameSpace/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/  this path is of custom theme only. If your theme is in vendor then in your theme create a directory with the name Magento_Theme and put the requirejs-config.js inside that.